# How to translate a list inside of a list to a single list with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have a object like the following:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public List<string> StudentNames { get; set; }
}
```

And I wanted to translate that into a list where each teacher name is paired with each student name.

```
public class TeacherStudent
{

    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

}
```

I know I can do it by looping like so:

```
var teachers = new List<Teacher>();
teachers.Add(new Teacher() { TeacherId = 1, TeacherName = "Teacher1", StudentNames = new List<string>() { "Student1", "Student2" } });
teachers.Add(new Teacher() { TeacherId = 2, TeacherName = "Teacher2", StudentNames = new List<string>() { "Student3", "Student4", "Student5" } });
teachers.Add(new Teacher() { TeacherId = 3, TeacherName = "Teacher3", StudentNames = new List<string>() { "Student6", "Student7" } });


var teacherStudents = new List<TeacherStudent>();
foreach(var teacher in teachers)
{

    foreach (var studentName in teacher.StudentNames)
    {
        teacherStudents.Add(new TeacherStudent() { TeacherId = teacher.TeacherId, TeacherName = teacher.TeacherName, StudentName = studentName });
    }

}
```

It just seems like there should be a way to do this with linq but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can a student have multiple teachers? So that `Student1` occurs on `Teacher1` and `Teacher2` for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
teachers.SelectMany(t =>
            t.StudentNames.Select(s => new TeacherStudent
            {
                TeacherId = t.TeacherId,
                TeacherName = t.TeacherName,
                StudentName = s
            }));
```